# How to have Yes and No as row values in an MS Access query of Yes/No fields?

Tags: ms-access

I want to make a query that returns a table result that looks like this:

[image]

Where the column headings are fields in one of my tables, and the numbers below are counts of yes/no entries for that field.

The problem I'm having is getting yes/no to show up at the beginning of the row. I would like it to be organized that way to better create charts out of the data.

Right now I only have queries that show me the 2 rows independently (one query for no results, one query for yes results)

Here is the original table:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for raw SQL code or for instructions on using the Access query builder?

Comment: either would be helpful! I tried playing with the SQL but just couldn't get it even close

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with just a query.  I think you'll need to do it with a report or form.  For your example output you'd have to run six different queries to get each of the individual numbers.  I was playing around with a union query, but it's not just the yes and no, you have to count each field independently.

Comment: @Steve Did you comment with regard to using Access' query tool, or with regard to SQL in general?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was talking about SQL in general, but I see your answer and that's pretty nifty assuming it works.  I've never used a COUNT in that fashion, I've always just used it in conjunction with a GROUP BY clause.  That's where I was hitting my issue is because all the fields would have to be grouped different ways

Answer (score 7):

Changing a little [Tim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48099994), here is my definitely working response.  I created a test table called `Table1` and included the fields named exactly the same as the OP in the screenshot.

```
SELECT 'yes' As Outcome, 
    SUM(IIF([Identified?] = -1, 1, 0)) As Identified, 
    SUM(IIF([DetailPlanned?] = -1, 1,0)) AS planned, 
    SUM(IIF([Realized?] = -1, 1,0)) AS realized
From Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'no' As Outcome, 
    SUM(IIF([Identified?] = 0, 1, 0)) As Identified, 
    SUM(IIF([DetailPlanned?] = 0, 1,0)) AS planned, 
    SUM(IIF([Realized?] = 0, 1,0)) AS realized
From Table1
```

Comment: This could be simplified: `SUM(IIF([Identified?], 1, 0))` for 'Yes' and `SUM(IIF([Identified?], 0, 1))` for 'No'

Comment: @SunKnight0 That's interesting and it works, thanks.  Does that basically change the first argument to "[Identified?] <> 0", or is that a trick that just works with Yes/No fields?

Comment: @Steve, I believe it's equivalent to `<> 0`, but you should try for yourself.

Comment: @Steve: Yes/No fields are inherently `True/False` by themselves, they do not need to be compared with a specific value. Internally `Yes/True` is `-1` and `No/False` is `0`, but in most cases you don't need to check for these values. In general 0=`False` and `anything but zero`=`True`. Care must also be taken in case the `Yes/No` field value can also be `NULL`.

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer because, while it is based off my answer, it adds value from the point of view or being tested on Access itself.  I have no issues with Steve's post :-)

Comment: @Cœur You're correct, but that only works in Access, not in SQL Server.  Also as SunKnight0 mentions, NULL in SQL Server will get included in the counts and so will blanks in Access.  So if 0 and NULL or blank have different meanings, this could cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general SQL query which hopefully can be adapted to Access:

```
SELECT
    'yes' AS outcome,
    SUM(IIF(identified = 'yes', 1, 0)) AS identified,
    SUM(IIF(planned    = 'yes', 1, 0)) AS planned,
    SUM(IIF(realized   = 'yes', 1, 0)) AS realized
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'no',
    SUM(IIF(identified = 'no', 1, 0)),
    SUM(IIF(planned    = 'no', 1, 0)),
    SUM(IIF(realized   = 'no', 1, 0))
FROM yourTable;
```

I don't know what values are actually stored in a column behind a checkbox.  You may have to replace yes/no with something else.

This code definitely works, just update the table name and it should work with the fields you have:

```
SELECT
    'yes' As Outcome, 
    SUM(IIF([identified] = -1, 1, 0)) As Identified, 
    SUM(IIF([planned] = -1, 1,0)) AS planned, 
    SUM(IIF([realized] = -1, 1,0)) AS realized
From yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'no' As Outcome, 
    SUM(IIF([identified] = 0, 1, 0)) As Identified, 
    SUM(IIF([planned] = 0, 1,0)) AS planned, 
    SUM(IIF([realized] = 0, 1,0)) AS realized
From yourTable;
```

Comment: this resulted in an error that reads "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(CASE WHEN identified = 'yes' THEN 1 END)'

Comment: @EmRoBeau I always forget that Access doesn't support `CASE` expressions; it uses `IIF()` instead.

Comment: @EmRoBeau If you're still getting a syntax error after his latest edit, swap out 'yes' for -1 and 'no' for 0.  So for the 2nd field in the select cause in the top section of the union you'd put SUM(IIF([Identified?] = -1, 1, 0)) AS identified

Comment: tried both of these edits, but now I'm getting an error that says "SELECT statement includes a reserved word or argument that is misspelled or missing punctuation."

Comment: @EmRoBeau check out my edit to Tim's answer.  That last section I successfully tested in Access

Comment: I'm sorry I see you're working hard to try and help me but these suggestions have not yet worked. When I use the code in my file I get errors such as 'circular reference' or 'type mismatch'. I think to start it would be helpful to see how 'yes' and 'no' could be generated in the first column

Comment: @EmRoBeau Sorry I don't think you're seeing my latest edit.  I've never edited a post here before and apparently it needs to be peer reviewed before it shows up so I'll just past it in the comments here.

Comment: @EmRoBeau SELECT 'yes' As Outcome, 
    SUM(IIF([Identified?] = -1, 1, 0)) As Identified, 
    SUM(IIF([DetailPlanned?] = -1, 1,0)) AS planned, 
    SUM(IIF([Realized?] = -1, 1,0)) AS realized
From Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'no' As Outcome, 
    SUM(IIF([Identified?] = 0, 1, 0)) As Identified, 
    SUM(IIF([DetailPlanned?] = 0, 1,0)) AS planned, 
    SUM(IIF([Realized?] = 0, 1,0)) AS realized
From Table1

Comment: @robinCTS the author accepted the edit. Don't roll it back.

Comment: Seeing all these comments is a bit like waking up in your apartment and finding out that someone threw a frat party the night before.  This banter belongs under Steve's answer, not under mine.

Comment: @Braiam Hey, I was just trying to be helpful and going by the meta post recommendation :-)  Tim may not have been aware of it, or noticed that Steve had reposted the edit as a separate answer. Now we have the untenable situation where without checking the edit histories it looks like Steve has plagiarised part of Tim's answer. I think I'll steer clear of this train wreck now ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My apologies. I thought you had organised the frat party ;-) I tried to clean up afterwards, but… Oh, well.